# Anyway to get both HTTPS and CDN in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My goal is to run multiple sites in a cluster (GKE). Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Each site should be on HTTPS (using cert-manager and letsencrypt) with HTTP/2
- Should be possible to enable Google CDN in the load balancer

**Method 1:**
I tried both https://www.getambassador.io/ and https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx. But both of them created TCP/UDP (layer 4) load balancer which doesn't allow CDN to be enabled

**Method 2:**
Later I tried default Ingress(https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) provided by GKE (layer 7), which creates HTTP(s) load balancer instead of TCP/UDP. CDN worked in this case. But I couldn't configure cert-manager. Couldn't find any docs for that. Not sure whether this load balancer terminates SSL by default which cannot be changed. I think there is also a limit of 15 domains in load balancer for SSL

Method 1 doesn't support CDN and Method 2 doesn't support cert-manager! Could find a way to get both HTTPS and CDN

Is there any way to get this work?

Comment: A quick search reveals https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs. Have you gone over it yet? I am not sure if they are actually "Let's Encrypt" certificates. But if your goal is just to automatically get TLS certificate with your Ingress then it appears to cover that. This would be used with your "Method 2" to do both automatic TLS and enable the CDN.

Comment: @AndyShinn yes, I've gone through it. But it only supports a max of 15 SSL certificates per load balancer

Comment: it's true that there is the 15 cert limit, but otherwise, this meets your needs. You'll just have to create multiple Ingress resources if you need more than 15 different certs

Comment: @Gijo Varghese, where exactly you failed when trying to configure cert-manager with GCE Ingress ?. It's straightforward, and requires only to use appropriate ingress scheme and ingress class in Ingress resource annotations. Take a look at [this github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/733#issue-434707146) example.